# Write-SqlTableData is giving error in powershell

Tags: powershell

I often use Write-SqlTableData on my computer but for some reasons I cant make it work on a different pc. I have tried to do this before:Install-Module SqlServer and Import-Module SQLPs but I still get the error below:

```
Write-SqlTableData : The term 'Write-SqlTableData' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, 
or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and 
try again.
```

Is there anything am doing wrong here?

Comment: The PowerShell modules are installed when sql is installed. They are optional, and different for different versions of sql. Are you using the same sql version? On the "different pc", is there a PowerShell folder in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\<ver>\Tools\`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have upgraded from powershell 4 to 5 and installed (install-module sqlserver) it then worked.

You can also check solution here: [Time to Upgrade Windows PowerShell to Version 5.0](http://wahlnetwork.com/2015/12/21/how-to-upgrade-windows-powershell-to-version-5-0/)